# Retry port binding with Kestrel and ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

We are creating a Windows service using ASP.Net Core and Kestrel. This service must bind to a specific port. To start the service we use the following code.

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
  CreateHostBuilder(config, args).Build().Run();           <=== IOException if port is already in use
}
```

The problem arises if this port is already in use. This code will then raise an exception and our application is terminated. However, the desired behavior is that our service logs the exception, waits for a minute and then tries again.

Of course we can catch the exception here in `main` and then wait for a minute, but I think that is not how this framework is intended to be used.

What is the best way to implement the desired behavior?

Comment: I don't think it's service's responsibility to respond to startup failure. Try returning non zero integer error code from `Main`, when you catch and log exception. Then configure "Recovery" tab of your service properties to "Restart service" after all failures and specify timeout.

Comment: For now I have choosen to go that way and see how it works about, thanks!